# How make custom class extend from LinearLayout and holds two views inside it

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a class extends from Vertical linerLayout and holds two views for ex ImageView and EditText how I can add and control the two views in the parent class

```
class GoogleSearchBar : LinearLayout {


constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: 
                Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
     }
  }
```

Comment: why don't you just use the XML

Comment: Consider https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: you can use xml layout file. It can be included in other xml layouts, or inflated in java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class GoogleSearchBar : LinearLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        setupView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        setupView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: 
                Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        setupView()
     }
    private void setupView(){
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null, false);
         addlayout.addView(view);
     }
}
```

create xml layout with name my_view.